# Sails.js - protect blueprint associations using policies

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In order to create a many-to-many association between models, I use the blueprints to access something like:

```
/api/item/1/tags/2
```

How can I protect this action using policies?

This action doesn't seem to fit any of the find/create/update/destroy policies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for custom routing here; the blueprint you're referring to is called `populate`, so it can be protected in your `config/policies.js` with:

```
ItemController: {

  populate: 'somePolicy'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
module.exports.routes = {

  //Set blueprints
  'GET /findAllUsers': {model: 'user', blueprint: 'find'},
  'GET /user/findAll': {blueprint: 'find'}
  'GET /user/findAll': {blueprint: 'find', model: 'pet'}
  // Set policies in routes
  '/foo': {policy: 'myPolicy'}
  // Mix of blueprints and policies
  'GET /mix-of-both': [
     {policy: 'isLoggued'},
     {blueprint: 'find', model: 'tag'}
   ]
}
```

Check the official docs: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html

I hope it helps!

Comment: Note that policy configs should always come *before* controller configs.  So your `/mix-of-both` config should have the order reversed, and your `/foo` config should have a controller or blueprint config chained to it.  The idea is that the policy is run, and then if it passes, some other business logic is run.

Comment: Ups! You're right about the order, it's fixed now. Thanks :)